# How can I add together the values of an array in CoffeeScript?

Tags: coffeescript

I have an array of numbers.
How can I add them together the easiest way in CoffeeScript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
numbers = [1, 2, 3]
sum = 0
(sum += num for num in numbers) # add each number in array to sum
```

Comment: Are you sure about that? `[NaN, NaN, NaN]` isn't the sum of that array.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is probably to use [`Array.prototype.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) just like you'd do in JavaScript:

```
numbers = [1..11]
sum     = numbers.reduce (m, n) -> m + n
# sum is now 66
```

Comment: `(sum += num for num in numbers)` is more understandable.

Comment: Only if you aren't familiar with (Java|Coffee)Script. This is the solution I'd expect to see from anyone that is familiar with JavaScript.

Comment: This loop format is featured on the top of the CoffeeScript page.

Answer (score 0):

Not the fastest implementation, but it is readable:

```
numbers = [1, 2, 3]
sum = 0
sum += num for num in numbers
```

Note the similarity to the other answer. This is the correct syntax, and it is identical to:

```
numbers = [1, 2, 3]
sum = 0
for num in numbers
  sum += num
```